# storing time interval in SQLite

Tags: python, date, sqlite, intervals, dateinterval

I need to create a database in Python using SQLite3 that can store the length of time for a song, including various other parameters such as song name and genre, that will be input manually.

What is the best way to store a fixed length of time? I understand that a DATE data type exists, but I'm not sure how to make it work in the way I require.

Comment: I would use an integer and store the number of seconds.  That would give me the greatest flexibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite's built-in [date and time functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html) support several format for timestamps, i.e., for absolute points in time.

But for time intervals, only numbers are supported (with the `NNN days`/`NNN hours`/`NNN minutes`/`NNN.NNN seconds` etc. modifiers), so you should store the number of seconds as a number.

If you do not want to use SQLite's built-in time functions to do computations on these values, then nothing of this matters, and you can store them in whatever format makes sense for your application.